# Determine the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let be $ (V,\|\cdot\|) $ a vector space with a norm $ \|\cdot\| $. Consider for an arbitrary $ x \in V $ an $ \varepsilon $-ball of $ x $: $$ B_\varepsilon (x) = \{y\in V:\ \|x-y\|<\varepsilon\}. $$

Then the closure of this ball is: $$ \overline{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}=\{y\in V:\ \|x-y\|\leq \varepsilon\}. $$

Problem: I cannot comprehend how you get to this expression. I only know this kind of **definition** of a closure of a set:

*Let be* $ (X,d) $ *a metric space and* $ T\subseteq X $. *The set* $$ \overline{T}=\bigcap(\{A\subseteq X:\ A\supseteq T\text{  is closed}\}) $$
*is called closure of* $ T $.

At first I pluged in the $ \varepsilon $-ball into this definition:

$$ \overline{B_\varepsilon(x)}=\bigcap(\{A\subseteq V:\ A\supseteq B_\varepsilon(x)\text{ is closed}\}) $$

From here I have no idea how to come the identity $$ \overline{B_\varepsilon (x)} = \{y\in V:\ \|x-y\|\leq \varepsilon\}. $$

Comment: Could you go one step further in your definitions: How is "closed" defined to you? There are a couple of more or less common options, and the choice may affect how this is proven.

Comment: I only know this fact: A set $ S $ is closed if the complement $ S^c $ is open. But this doesn't help me out from here.

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is closed and contains $B_{\epsilon} (x)$ then it contains $\{x: \|x-y\|\leq \epsilon\}$: Take any $y$ with $\|x-y\|\leq \epsilon$ and consider Let $0<t<1$ and $z=x+t(y-x)$. Then $z \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$. We have to prove that $y \in C$. If not then $y$ is in the open set $C^{c}$ so there exists $r>0$ such that $B_{r} (y)\subseteq C^{c}$. But $\|z-y\| <r$ if  $t >1-r/\|x-y\|$. Thus $z \in C^{c}$ which is a subset of $B_{\epsilon} (x)^{c}$. We have arrived at a contradiction. [$A^{c}$ denotes complement of $A$].  We have proved that $  \{x: \|x-y\|\leq \epsilon\} \subseteq \overline {B_{\epsilon} (x)}$.

The reverse inclusion follows from the fact that $\{x: \|x-y\|\leq \epsilon\}$ is itself a closed set which contains $B_{\epsilon} (x)$.

Comment: At this point I have not the equiptment to talk about convergence in vector spaces. I only have the definition. In my script the convergence comes a bit later and there is mentioned that is "very easy" to check the identity in my question.